# Unable to detect Row inserts in Google sheets through google apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I'm new to Google app scripting. Currently, am trying to create a insert row detector and update values in that new row based on values of the row right on top of it. Reading the docs & other stuff online, I have created the following code. But the issue is that it doesn't work.

How can I create a generic row detector or how can I fix this?

Code:

```
function onChange(e){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('green');
  //e.range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + ' getActiveUser().getEmail(): ' + Session.getEffectiveUser() );
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('red');
    // a row or many rows were inserted

    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "UIDAICheck") {
      // Let's set the formula for calculating the End Date / Time of inserted lines    
      sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('blue');
      var iRow = e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow();
      var iRows = e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getNumRows(); 

      var aRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
      aRange.setValue('555')

    }
  }
}
```

If there are non-code related changes like installing installable triggers or something, please share how I maybe able to connect those dots as well to being able to automatically fill cell values on row inserts? Admittedly, I'm new to this whole territory..

PS: I dont think any part of this code is working. This is my execution transcript:

```
[17-09-23 13:25:46:950 IST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:46:950 IST] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:46:950 IST] Range.getLastRow() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:46:950 IST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:46:950 IST] Range.getLastColumn() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:47:049 IST] Session.getActiveUser() [0.098 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:47:050 IST] User.getEmail() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:47:050 IST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[17-09-23 13:25:47:058 IST] Starting execution
[17-09-23 13:25:47:103 IST] Execution failed: Script function not found: onEdit [0 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Do you know what causes the onEdit error? is there any more code besides the onChange function? any installed triggers?

Comment: Not entirely sure.  Well initially I had a onEdit trigger which worked just fine, but the code editor run button has the ability to select only one function, so I removed that and tried running this. Anyway, no part of this code is proprietary and can easily be recreated by anyone whos done this before. Just put it there to show what I tried. I think its better if you could write the basic code afresh.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but give it a try.

```
function MyChange(e){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getRange('A1').getBackground()!='#ff0000')
  {
    sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('#00ff00');
  }
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") 
  {
    sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('#ff0000');
    if (sheet.getName()=="UIDAICheck") 
    {
      sheet.getRange('A1').setBackground('#0000ff');
      sheet.getActiveRange().setValue('555');
    }
  }
}
```

Installing the onChange trigger:

[image]