# Google Sheets script to insert a timestamp on a row inserted from a form? How to detect the inserted row using onChange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to write a script that will insert a timestamp on rows (in the 23rd column) inserted into a Google sheet from a form (not a google form; it is some other vendor that sends the data to the sheet and does not pass a timestamp).

I have been trying to script something from examples, but I cannot seem to get it to work. The script I have so far is as follows:

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('timestamp')
  .forSpreadsheet('spreadsheet_id_goes_here')
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function timestamp(e){

  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 23).setValue(new Date());
  } 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The problem is that your script is using `e.range` but the change event object doesn't include a `range` property.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you. I am such a noob to this that I am still not sure how to correct the issue. How can I include a range property in the event object?

Comment: Have you already read the linked question?

Comment: Try using `getActiveRange()` Related: [Unable to detect Row inserts in Google sheets through google apps scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46377365/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén This question doesn't state anything about "deleting" events. I'm inclined to reopen it. The linked question states it's impossible, whereas this is possible. Although the issue is `e.range` as you've suggested, I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @aguadamuz Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416583/

Comment: I went ahead and reopened this. And there are interesting answers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

The `onChange` Event object `e` does not  contain  the key `range`. It does not provide information about the `range` directly.

#### Solution:

In most cases of `onChange` and specifically in yours, where  change type is `INSERT_ROW`, the `activeRange` represents the current row that was inserted.

```
function timestamp(e){
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){
    const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sh.getRange(sh.getActiveRange().getRow(), 23).setValue(new Date());
  } 
}
```

#### Related Answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416583/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750720/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113286/

Answer (score 2):

You see `e.range.getRow()` method. so you have check row number comes is valid or not.
otherwise, you have used `sh.getLastRow()` method to add a new record.

```
function timestamp(e){
  if(e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow()+1;
    sh.getRange(lastRow ,23).setValue(new Date);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for the `onChange` event object, `e` can contain information about the following:

- `authMode` - which is a value from the `ScriptApp.AuthMode` enum.;
- `changeType` - which represents the type of change (`EDIT`, `INSERT_ROW`, `INSERT_COLUMN`, `REMOVE_ROW`, `REMOVE_COLUMN`, `INSERT_GRID`, `REMOVE_GRID`, `FORMAT`, or `OTHER`).;
- `triggerUid` - which is the ID of trigger that produced this event.;
- `user` - which represents a `User` object, representing the active user, if available.

Therefore, in order to insert the timestamp needed you will have to make use of one of the above options.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).